how do i install flipper on ubuntu 23.04
I want to install flipper on ubuntu for debugging perpose
Installed a file with name is flipper-server.tgz also searched everywhere not a single answer found, all tutorials i found where with different packages samples
I search everywere for an answer and all of tutorials where different than any process that i was able to reproduce on my own

Link on flipper official page is broken you have to just follow :- here
or
git clone https://github.com/facebook/flipper.git
cd flipper/desktop
yarn
yarn start

